# How to run SQL Statement to multiple databases at a time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a PostgreSQL DB server that has 30 databases of same table, field and data. Now if I need to add a menu item I need to run insert statement to all database that consume huge time.

Is there any way or available options that I can follow to run insert statement once, my all databases/selected databases will be update at a time.

I am currently run insert statement to all database individually. It costs huge time.

Answer (score 0):

The databases are isolated in PostgreSql and does't have access to each other unless FDW connectivity is not configured.

You can use python/other scripting to update / insert in multiple databases on single click.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and appreciate more suggestions.